# Div is not starting from a random position

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all i have seen many answer in stakeoverflow but none of these helped me!!! I want to start my div from a random position and then it will move. Rather then it shows from a static position and then it comes to a random position and then it start to move. I tried to declare my top and left by javascript in

```
$( document ).ready(function()
```

but that does not help

HTML

```
<div class="ballarea" id="ballarea1">
        <div class="circle type" id="ball"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.circle{
border-radius: 50%;
border: thin;
border-color: blue;
}
.type {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
border: 5px solid blue;
position: relative;
}

.ballarea{
width: 300px;
height: 400px;
border: solid black;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var i=0;
var j=0;
function ballMove(){
var d=document.getElementById("ball");
var temp=i;
if(i<1)
{   
     i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200));
     j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200));

}
for(;i<2+temp;i++,j++)
{
    d.style.left=i+"px";
    d.style.top=j+"px";
}
//document.getElementById('ball').style.display = 'block';

}

function timeChange()
{
setInterval( ballMove, 500);
}
```

[image]

Now at first it starts from a static position like the following and then it start from a random position. I want to show it from a random position not from a static position

Comment: set up a fiddle please

Comment: did you try hiding it at first and then showing it after the random position is set?

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding it at first, because your script run when your DOM is ready.

```
<div class="ballarea" id="ballarea1">
        <div class="circle type" id="ball" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>
```

Then when your script is running, show it

```
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
function randomBall(){
  var d = document.getElementById("ball");
  i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200));
  j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200));
  d.style.left = i+"px";
  d.style.top = j+"px";
  d.style.display = "block";
}

function ballMove(){
  var d=document.getElementById("ball");
  i += 2;
  j += 2;
  d.style.left = i+"px";
  d.style.top = j+"px";
}

function timeChange()
{
  randomBall();
  setInterval( ballMove, 500);
}
```

Comment: I tried it. It does not work. It is same as the before.

Comment: i dont quite understand what do you want to achive with this `var temp=i;
if(i<1)
{   ` and this `for(;i<2+temp;i++,j++)
{`

Comment: this helps it moving. Every time i is increasing(I initialize it to 0 at first) and i want it to move 2 px in every 500ns so i update i and as I want it to move 2 more px than the current value of i. So I store the value in temp (as each iteration i is increasing i cant put i in condition it will be infinte)

Comment: just updated my answer. dont forget to add `style="display:none"` in your ball